# "Install update to keep device running smoothly" dialog comes but when try to install, it stuck at installing update

Tags: ota-update

On my Android phone, I'm getting the below dialog but when I try to install an update, it is stuck.

[image]

Please note that I have 20.83GB of free space in the Internal storage. I tried when the battery is 100% charged and also tried on "Mobile Data" as well as "WiFi" connection.

Anything else I can try? Also, I don't want to Factory Reset the phone.

More info about the device:

- [LAVA Z6](https://www.gsmarena.com/lava_z6-10666.php)
- Android version 11
- Build number: LAVA_LMX06_SW_V12_HW_V1.0_20220316

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it by clearing system cache partition using the recovery. So no need to factory reset and not loss any data!
After wiping system cache partition, we need to download the updates again. Then it will install nicely.